# Using an ERC20 contract to create blocks of newly minted tokens

Tags: contract-design

I am wanting to find out the best method to create a contract that allows for an initial release of 1M tokens (US$5 par value) and then at 98% of hard cap, another 1M tokens is minted and made available for sale. This process would need to be supported in up to 20 new mints.

The issue is this - at each new mint, does the value of the token (if it is traded on an exchange) get released at the original value (US$5 par value) or will they release at the current traded price?

Does anyone have a code example of something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... and then at 98% of hard cap, another 1M tokens is minted and made available for sale

If I'd knowingly bought some of your tokens during your ICO at $5 a pop, and then you sprung another million on the community, multiple times, I'd be pretty annoyed... :-)

You can dictate the price of your tokens, in ether, during the ICO when people are "buying" directly from your contract. There may well be a way to fix the price *in dollars* by using an oracle service to adjust the rate you're selling at on the fly (to maintain $5/token).

> The issue is this - at each new mint, does the value of the token (if it is traded on an exchange)

Once your token is out there, and being traded on exchanges, the market sets the price. If you're flooding the market with multiple millions of further tokens, expect the prices on the exchanges to plummet.

If you're still trying to sell your tokens at $5 from your contract, but on the exchanges they're trading below that (because you've inflated the supply), then you're probably not going to have much luck.

Comment: Thanks Richard - this is the logic that myself and another founder member have presented. We just have a person on the team that wanted this approach. We prefer to do one mint and then the market set the price or there is a function that allows you to mint as you go.

Comment: Our token is utilities based - so investors receive the token to then be able to purchase products. Funding is used for research and development - we already have working prototypes. But we didn't consider ourselves as a crowdsale token.